# IN_APP_NOTIFY with in-app version 3

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm playing with in-app code from Google. I read several documentation but I didn't understand a couple of things. First of all a bit of context: I need to listen to changes in the ownership state and I can't simply re-query the inventory as the InApp example does in the main activity because I'm writing a plug for other app so my entry point is not an activity but a broadcast receiver. I understood that version 3 is based on a periodic check of the inventory, indeed in the example there is no code to receive any intent. Now my questions:

1. Is the IN_APP_NOTIFY valid in version 3 of the API?
2. Do I need even other intent as PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED&co?
3. Is there any v3 example to understand better how the IN_APP_NOTIFY broadcast receiver works?

Comment: Are you talking about the listener `OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener` passed into `launchPurchaseFlow`? I'm assuming you'v been through http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html?

Comment: The problem is that with in-app v3 if you at start request the "inventory" each time there isn't any problem because you've got always an updated situation. My app is plug for other app so my entry point is not a main activity but a broadcast receiver, so it's difficult for me to do that. There isn't an example of IN_APP_NOTIFY in v3 due to check *each time* but if you want to avoid this check each time you have to listen to this intent.

Comment: @greywolf82: even when you are using this as plug or library project, you can create `activity` and use it simply by registering them inside  `manifest` file of your main project.

Comment: @MehulJoisar Of course but the user never open it, so I can't associate to it nothing.

Comment: @greywolf82: when you receive broadcast, you can start activity, because even it will required to show some UI while processing purchase.

Comment: @MehulJoisar The receiver is designed to process request from the host app, it shouldn't start any activity and I can't check anything inside the receiver. If It was so easy I wouldn't asked to stackoverflow.